# Drupal overlay is not working for content links

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs

I have installed my own custom theme in Drupal 7.29. 
Overlay is not working for my content links such as

```
http://localhost/node/add#overlay-context=.
http://localhost/node/add
http://localhost/node/add/page
http://localhost/node/add/article
```

But for other links overlay works just fine

```
http://localhost/node/add/page#overlay=admin/structure
http://localhost/node/add/page#overlay=admin/structure/block
http://localhost/node/add/page#overlay=admin/structure/types
```

Overlay Working

[image: overlay works for other links]

Overlay not Working for content links 
[image: Overlay not working]

Please help me solve this problem. Any help is appriciated

thanks

Comment: Look at your paths compared to the ones that work... #overlay=admin

Comment: sry i did not understand ? where you look for this path ? are you asking me to search for it in module ? -- @AlexGill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure that the user that is trying to use the overlay has the appropriate permissions to do so (the permission is called: **"Access the administrative overlay"**). If you are trying to add/edit content as admin, then that's not the problem.

Also, make sure that in **admin/appearance** page, the option **"Use the administration theme when editing or creating content"** is selected. Notice, that if a role does not have the permissions to use the administrative theme (or the overlay for that matter), the users with the specific role will be adding/editing content through the default theme of your site.

Comment: You have saved my day :D .... In admin/appearance page, the option "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" was not selected. I just selected it and it is working just fine ... Thanks a lot :)